# First concat two columns and count the unique occurrences of the combinations, and update a column with the product

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc

I've got this working query:

```
SELECT  jobtitle
       ,department
       ,COUNT({ fn CONCAT(jobtitle, department) }) AS occurrences
FROM mytable
GROUP BY jobtitle
        ,department
```

But now I'd like to update all records of the same table by updating the `int` column `number`, and fill it using the value of the `occurrences` variable created in the query where both jobtitle and department values match.

It took about half a day to make the query work. But this is a little too complex. 
I hope someone can help

Kind regards,

Frans

Comment: `COUNT({ fn CONCAT(jobtitle, department) })` isn't valid T-SQL. Are you *sure* that's working? Sample data and expected results will greatly help us here as you don't actually tell us what the the problem. What have you tried to solve the issue and why didn't it work (like I said, that above won't work, braces (`{}`) aren't used in T-SQL).

Comment: @Larnu That's an ODBC function that gets translated to the proper native syntax. Probably unnecessary but explains why it works. `count(*)` is equivalent anyway.

Comment: Makes sense to tag that too then, thanks @shawnt00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a join of the table with your query in the update statement:

```
update m
set m.number = t.occurrences
from mytable m inner join (
  select jobtitle, department,
    count(concat(jobtitle, department)) as occurrences
  from mytable
  group by jobtitle, department
) t on t.jobtitle = m.jobtitle and t.department = m.department
```

But I believe that you could also use `count(*)` instead of `count(concat(jobtitle, department))`

Comment: Yes that is it. It works exactly the way I want it. Thank you very much for your time and energy.

Comment: Thanks for educating me ;-) I just did

Answer (score 0):

Your `concat()` expression is basically the same as `count(*)` (as long as neither value is null.)

```
with data as (
    select *, count(*) over (partition by jobtitle, department) as cnt
    from T
)
update data set num = cnt;
```

Also be aware that pairs of concatenated strings can result in the same value where the components were unequal. `"A" + "BC"` is identical to `"AB" + "C"` for instance. In your case I doubt that could happen but it's an unnecessary complexity.

You can see it in action here: https://rextester.com/CEVRX27211

Comment: Thank you for your support. I 've tried to use your code but is caused an error. But I solved it using the code of Forpas (see below). Thanks any way for your time and help.

Comment: @Frans Next time please report the error. Since you didn't provide any schema detail I had to use placeholders "T" and "num".

Comment: @Frans The error was probably the one that said that `dept` was not a valid column. That was a typo which has been corrected.